# Dig utility sometimes misses the answer packet

Tags: macos, dns, dig

I just discovered that dig utility sometimes misses the answer packet from recursive resolver. I repeat the same query multiple times and from time-to-time dig utility has to resend query packet (with the same transaction ID). However, Wireshark clearly see the answer from the first attempt arrived to NIC.

I recorded the screen: https://youtube.com/watch?v=I63LA0m9zzE

DiG 9.10.6
MacOS 12.6

What can cause this? I tried multiple DNS recursive servers and also multiple domain names for test, situation is the same.

Thanks,
Blažej

Comment: New video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I63LA0m9zzE

Comment: [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment. Your video is marked private. It’s better to explain your problem within the body of your question. You can use screenshots to achieve a detailed question

Comment: Yeah, I could not find edit link. Thanks